# Can 'hardly' replace 'rarely', or must I say 'hardly ever'?

Tags: word-choice

I wrote the sentence

> Fiona goes to the theater *once in a blue moon.*

which means that

> Fiona *rarely* goes to the theater.

Can I use *hardly* instead of *rarely* in the sentence?, resulting in

> Fiona *hardly* goes to the theater.

Or must I use *hardly ever*? A dictionary  cannot answer this question.

Comment: I found "Fiona *hardly* goes to the theater" fine at a glance, although thinking about it and reading the answers, "Fiona *hardly ever* goes to the theater" does sound better. However, if you want to say that she used to, but doesn't go very much anymore, the way to say it would be "Fiona *hardly* goes to the theater these days/anymore/now/etc."

Answer (score 11):

You use [hardly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hardly) to say:

> - ***only just; almost not:***

- To convey the meaning of "rarely" you have to use  "hardly ever".

> - *I could hardly hear her at the back.
>     The party had hardly started when she left.
>     He hardly ate anything/He ate hardly anything.
>     **We hardly ever (= almost never) go to concerts.** 
>     Hardly had a moment passed before the door creaked open.*

(Cambridge Dictiinary)

Comment: However, the "ever" may be omitted and you'll still be understood. In that sense, "hardly" is often used in place of "barely" nowadays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It might just be me, but omitting the "ever" sounds off to my ear.

Comment: @ghoppe: I hardly hear the phrase with the "ever" present :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to me that means you struggle to hear it. I can hardly hear you over the noise of the airport. Etc... I'm with ghoppe. To mean you rarely do something you would say you hardly ever do it.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, I get what you and the others have said, and I am saying that it would still be understood as intended, where I come from (which, by the way, is England). People don't do a scientific grammatical analysis when they're having a chat.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see what coming from England changes. I, too, come from England and have lived here 34 years (my whole life). I still hardly ever hear people use "hardly" to mean "rarely". :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I live in Central Canada, and it's not a matter of whether you'll be understood, it's a matter of whether you'll sound like a native speaker — which is what ELL is all about. It seems I'm not alone in believing saying "hardly" by itself for "rarely" is unidiomatic. Whew.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, for that specific example.

For discrete things like going to the theatre I'd take the "ever" as implied or even unnecessary.

With a variable thing like eating "hardly" and "hardly ever" are fairly different:
"Hardly eats" vs "Hardly ever eats" => "doesn't eat very much" vs "doesn't eat very often"
In the first example the total amount of food eaten is small but there's no comment on frequency and in the second there's a long time between meals but no indication of how large each meal is.

But for binary things, like going to the theatre, they mean much the same thing. This is because you can't go to the theatre "a little bit"; you either go or you don't. As such having a low total amount of visits to the theatre and not visiting very often are the same.

Or at least that's my perspective as a native speaker of British English.